# Unity - How to tell whether translate function will take object outside certain bounds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Alright Im using a joystick to move my camera in Unity like this:

```
moveVector = (transform.right * joystick.Horizontal + transform.forward * joystick.Vertical);

transform.Translate(moveVector * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

However I need to limit where my camera can move to within the bounds of a boxcollider (the room, stored in a variable). Ive tried this but this always returns true even when the camera moves out of range:

```
print(GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().room.bounds.Contains(moveVector));
```

How can I detect whether the translation would move the camera out of bounds, and if this is true, not do the translation with the move vector?

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of the bounds?

Comment: You can also use several gameObjects as your bounds and then if your camera collide with them, disable camera movement to that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the displacement of the camera ('moveVector') to determine whether the camera is in the bounding box. Instead you should use the position of the camera,

```
gameObject.transform.Position
```

or the future position of the camera,

```
gameObject.transform.position + moveVector
```

to determine whether it is in the bounding box or not. Thus, modify your code as follows:

```
GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>().room.bounds.Contains(camera.transform.position + moveVector)
```

Make sure your 'room' variable is of type **Collider** in the 'PlayerController' script,

```
 var room = GetComponent<Collider>();
```